# Leiningen Crash with Autodoc (sh does not exist)

Tags: clojure, leiningen, autodoc

I am trying to use Clojure autodoc in my project.  My project.clj looks like this:

```
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
:plugins [[lein-autodoc "0.9.0"]])
```

When I do `lein autodoc` I get this error

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: sh does not exist, compiling:(leiningen/autodoc.clj:1:1)
```

I do have the binary sh

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

lein-autodoc does not work with leiningen 2.X. The error message you see comes from [this line](https://github.com/tomfaulhaber/lein-autodoc/blob/master/src/leiningen/autodoc.clj#L4):

```
[leiningen.compile :only [sh]] ; in 2.0 this moves to leiningen.eval
```

Obviously this has nothing to do with /bin/sh.

You may want to check out [Codox](https://github.com/weavejester/codox).